How to extract link of iframe from a page after automating click
I'm trying to extract links of iframe in a webpage it has a section with class
This class a section of video source.
.list-box

After clicking the videos which are in this class it loads the video dynamically without refreshing the page. I tried to automate the click using JS and it didn't give me links which I tried to achieve using JS. I tried clicking the element with class .list-box every 2 second but it failed giving me the links of iframe.
At first there is video 1 so video 1 has an iframe which is Current video URL, here it does give me the link of the current iframe so there is video 2 which needs to be clicked everytime in order to get the iframe src so for that I tried automating the click but it only give me the link of the Current Video but I want to get the link of every video element which are present.
Here is my JS code
const currentVideoIframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

if (currentVideoIframe) {
    console.log('Current url', currentVideoIframe.src);
} else {
    console.log('Nothing');
}

// The main element 
const videoContainer = document.querySelector(".list-box");

const clickElementEvery2Seconds = () => {
    const listBox = document.getElementsByClassName("list-box")[0];
    if (listBox) {
        listBox.click(); // Initiate click on the list box

        // Wait 2 seconds after the click to process iframes
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (videoContainer) {
                const videoIframes = videoContainer.querySelectorAll('iframe');
                videoIframes.forEach((iframe, index) => {
                    const videoUrl = iframe.src;
                    console.log(`Links ${index + 1}: ${videoUrl}`);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Nothing');
            }
        }, 2000); // 2 seconds

    } else {
        console.log("Element not found");
    }
};

setInterval(clickElementEvery2Seconds, 5000);


Thank You for your time. I hope for a help.

Maybe this can help. If not, can you share the page you're trying to operate on? Many reasons can cause your code not to working and it's hard to tell without seeing the target code

The page I am working on specially requires log in credentials to operate on. You will get those video list once you've logged in and you can access that page. However I think there's some way for it.

I see. Unfortunately I don't have ideas without seeing the we page :/
